# Diffie Hellman to AES

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I am trying to create an application that can send data from a client to a server using encrypted data. I have set up a basic Diffie Hellman key exchange in Java and I was just wondering how I would convert that to a AES-128 key. Here are the numbers that my key exchange is producing:
`p: 45739334052801211486383982115714395642859523615469431203095063293408205085850655737540408983027523682219373484935815737826696483347058644040214365601698451568563654746844010747338983871136644386557631185640042912749789107007323073169713214532843785763128771045651074137977867781277726926260077346003
g: 405
produced key: 36248441610316046373940723150439573936645456312032028064365240345591632292456385336418395841257359594423512887912569551847749513145040862559588574541468845827085159018247962009639778000068069176753753861222140233559881791396088762185913485540314156993368037042615619321223426679365899278177180176354`

Both p and the produced key are 299 characters long. I have tried to figure this out myself and read about hashing the produced key with SHA-256, this is the result:
`SHA-256: 4631d862806f2c22ae28959a8ffb441789ab306468d6bf04d87435dd81890519`

I can not however see how I can turn any of these into a 16 byte (128 bit) key. An example of which is {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}. Do I take the first 16 numbers of my result? 


Any help or information would be amazing and I would be very thankful. If any more information is required please just ask me.

Comment: Have you considered TLS?

Comment: I have not looked into it, however I will now that you have brought it too my attention. Than you very much.

Comment: Just performing DH is not secure in itself, as always, listen to codes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (Optional) Use 128-bit values for `a` and `b` secret parameters of key exchange.
2. Convert the resulting value `s` into *byte* array and take *any* 16 elements. You *don't* need to dump `s` into hex string, or to hash that string.

Comment: If I was to go with option two, would always taking the first 16 bytes suffice or would that some how make it less secure? Or rather should I take a random assortment of bytes and then tell the server/client what positions to take their bytes from?

Comment: I was wondering the same, but taking the first (leftmost for big endian systems) 16 bytes [could suffice](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9418/how-random-is-the-shared-secret-in-the-diffie-hellman-key-agreement/9428#9428). To use a the "right" cryptographic method, you should use one or more calls to a KBKDF (key based key derivation method) though, e.g. HKDF. Only using SHA-256 and taking the first 128 bytes of the result can be seen as a poor mans KDF.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a [key derivation function](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), which will take as input any bitstring containing sufficient randomness (such as a [Diffie–Hellman](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) shared secret) and "scramble" it to produce one or more uniformly random bitstrings of fixed length, suitable e.g. for use as [AES](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) keys.

There are many standardized KDFs you could use, but if you want a specific recommendation, I'm rather fond of [HKDF](http://webee.technion.ac.il/%7Ehugo/kdf/) ([RFC 5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869)).
It is an "extract-and-expand" type KDF, which means that it first processes the input string into an internal master key string (referred to as "PRK" in the specification), which can then be used to derive an arbitrary amount of key material.

HKDF is a generic high-level construction that can be instantiated using any secure [cryptographic hash function](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) such as [SHA-2](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), so, even if your crypto library doesn't offer a built-in HKDF implementation, it's not hard to write one yourself.  The specification in the RFC is quite well written and readable, and I'd very much recommend taking a few minutes to read it.

Like most KDFs, the expansion step of HKDF takes in an optional "info" string, which is used to tweak the key derivation process so that the same input string (or PRK) can be reused to derive multiple (effectively) independent keys, as long as a different "info" string is used for each key.  (The extraction phase, used to derive the PRK from the input string, also takes a "salt" parameter that has a similar effect.)

One think HKDF does *not* do is [key stretching](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching), which is useful (some would say essential) if the input is a user-chosen password.  If you need that, you can use e.g. [PBKDF2](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [scrypt](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) instead.  (It's also possible to replace just the extraction phase of HKDF with PBKDF2, and use the expansion phase as is; in fact, this is the method I would recommend for generating more than one hash block's worth of key material with PBKDF2.)  Fortunately, with Diffie–Hellman, the shared secret has sufficient entropy that key stretching is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the information, however I think that for now I am just going to take random bytes from my result and tell the server/client what positions I look then from. I will however look into what you have said in the future.

Comment: @user2124641: [That's probably OK](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9418/how-random-is-the-shared-secret-in-the-diffie-hellman-key-agreement), but I'd still recommend using HKDF. It's really very simple, as long as you have a hash function like SHA-256 available.